# How to output a jQuery variable with php Laravel to send mail with Mail-gun

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-5, mailgun

I have created an AJAX contact form which sends to MailGun and it works fine but the message does not display for some reason. As you can see from the picture. [image]

This is the HTML template for the e0-mail that is sent to Mailgun:

contact.blade.php

```
<h3>You have a new contact via the contact form!</h3>
<div>
    {{ $bodyMessage }}
</div>

<p>Sent via Hell</p>
```

I don't think the contact.blade.php is picking up the {{ bodyMessage }} variable.

This is the jQuery for the AJAX form:

```
$("form.wpcf7-form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var token = $("input[name=_token]").val(); // The CSRF token
    var first_name = $("input[name=first-name]").val();
    var last_name = $("input[name=last-name]").val();
    var email = $("input[name=email]").val();
    var phone = $("input[name=phone]").val();
    var bodyMessage = $("textarea[name=message]").val();

    $.ajax({
       type:'POST',
       url:'/contact',
       dataType: 'json',
       data:{_token: token, first_name:first_name, last_name:last_name, email:email, phone:phone, bodyMessage:bodyMessage},
       success:function(data){
           $(".email-success-messge").append(data.success).fadeIn(999);

       }
    });
});
```

Here is the ContactController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Post;
use Mail;
use Session;

class ContactController extends Controller
{
    public function postContact(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request, ['email' => 'required|email'] );

        $data = array(
            'first_name' => $request->first_name,
            'last_name' => $request->last_name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'phone' => $request->phone,
            'bodyMessage' => $request->message
        );

        Mail::send('emails.contact', $data, function($message) use ($data){
            $message->from($data['email']);
            $message->to('j***r@*********.co.uk');
            $message->subject('Contact Details');
        });

        return response()->json(['success' => 'Your E-mail was sent! Allegedly.'], 200);

    }
}
```

I honestly don't understand why it takes the message details like the sender's email and subject but not the message.

Comment: `'bodyMessage' => $request->message` should be `'bodyMessage' => $request->bodyMessage` as you are sending it as bodyMessage through ajax

Comment: @JohnKlakegg, thats actualy an good answer.

Comment: @JohnKlakegg I owe you big time. Post it as an answer.

Comment: @JafarSalami You're welcome, helps with a couple of extra eyes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting my comment as answer.

`'bodyMessage' => $request->message` should be `'bodyMessage' => $request->bodyMessage` as you are sending it as `bodyMessage` through ajax.